# Not getting result from unlabeled class

Tags: java, netbeans, weka

```
    Instances new_testing_data = Filter.useFilter(testing_data, remove2);
    new_testing_data.setClassIndex(new_testing_data.numAttributes()-1);

    double pred;
    String actual, prediction, adm_no;

    for (int i = 0; i < new_testing_data.numInstances(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Classifying Instances " + i);
        pred = j48.classifyInstance(new_testing_data.instance(i));
....
....
```

I have a set of train set with labeled class and test set with unlabeled class,
I need to get prediction result on test set. Am i doing it right from above code?Any guidance would be very appreciated, this project had been strangle me for all days and nights.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
            fc.buildClassifier(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot build classifier");
        }
        //<---building of the classifier ends
        //Classification--->
        clsLabel = new double[testData.numInstances()]; //holds class label of the test documents
        //for each test document--->
        for (int i = 0; i < testData.numInstances(); i ++){
            try {
                clsLabel[i] = fc.classifyInstance(testData.instance(i));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error from Classification.classify(). Cannot classify instance");
            }
            testData.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel[i]);
        }//end for
        //<---classification ends
```

Comment: Do I need to input my test data with class attribute column? or just simply leave it blank and it will fill up with prediction results?

Comment: The unknown labels will be '?'

Comment: beside filling my test set class attribute as "?", do i need to modify my code? does it understand?

Comment: If you want your test set to have labelled data after you run your code then check out my last line-you will need that.